# Launching installed Amazon app on android using appium

Tags: android, automation, appium

I want to launch an already installed app on android emulator without providing .app or .zip path. Since I do not have those files with me now. Is it possible to launch already installed app in android emulator using appium? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newpower.apkmanager&hl=en in your mobile and can easily get .apk file for your app. Which you can store it in your PC and give the path in appium

Comment: Yes I can do that. But i need to do some settings in my app(after installing it). I dont think i can do that. So i want to launch already installed app. Can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is way to launch the app. 
Use the adb commands to open the app.

adb shell monkey -p in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping  -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1

in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping - is the package ID of the amazon app which is already installed on the android device.

If you want to get the list of apps package ID form your android device, then run the below command to see the ID list.
adb shell pm list packages -3

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "LGD7229bf02741");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity");
    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}
```